# Compare multiple 1D arrays to other multiple 1D arrays row by row looking for differences

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, comparison

I've been racking my brain for a while now to solve some problem that I have not managed to solve as I'm still a begginer.

Everyday I receive from a provider, an excel file with 15 columns and a variable amount of rows.
Everyday **I need to compare this file with my own file, row by row in order to check if there is some row missing in any of both files** and copy the missing row in another sheet.

**Comparing 8 elements of each row is enough** to perform the comparison row by row.

**It is possible and probable to find that there are multiple rows that are entirely identical** and that normally, also need to be found in both files as any other rows. 
Doing a loop would be higly time inefficient and I now I could use the very efficient **Dictionnary method**. **But how could I manage the issue with the multiple identical rows? Even identical, these rows are conceptually independent** and I need to check they are present in both files.
**I understand that an 1D array can only be 1 time in the dictionary**. So, when comparing my file versus the other and looping through the Dictionnary with "If element.DictExists", if there are duplicated rows, probably the script will just match the first occurence and not the next one.  Am I wrong?

I'm not here to request code. Rather, I come here in search of wisdom and guidance.
Hope you can help me. Thx

Comment: Theoretically you could use [`WorksheetFunction.CountIfs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.countifs) with 8 criteria to do this.

Comment: If you want to use a dictionary with a composite key of those 8 cells, then you can use an array (or Collection) of row numbers as the value if there are likely to be multiple matches.

Comment: "I understand that an 1D array can only be 1 time in the dictionary" - not clear what you mean by this

Comment: @Tim Williams you are right. The idea is using those 8 cells as the key value for every row. But what I meant is that you can just store in the dictionnary 1 key with an specific value. You cannot store more than 1 composite key with the same value... and that is the problem. There are multiple identical rows that will generate the same key already stored.

Comment: OK so if the key is the same then group the "same" rows in an array or collection in the dictionary's Value for that key.  "Even identical, these rows are conceptually independent" - it's not clear if the rows are really "identical" in aspects other than sharing the 8 key columns, and how you want to check they exist in both files.  Some sample data would go a long way here.

Comment: Hello, I've just post some sample data :-)